# Can you do better than "Sock-Wasp"?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I met this beautiful fellow when I was choosing my socks this morning. It seems I had found her cozy place. A stowaway, supposedly sneaked into my bag while camping, and me taking her all the way home. She just sat there for about a minute (probably just as tired as me, thinking "Duuuuuude, why did you wake me?"), then stretched her neck and and set off, searching for a calm spot to get her 5 more minutes.

[image: cute buzzer]

Ca. 3 cm long. At home in Austria/Southern Germany.

I searched the internet a bit, and I *think* it's a female wasp, possibly [*Dolichovespula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichovespula) because of the pointy snout(?). I don't think it's a [commom wasp](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemeine_Wespe), due to its size. Also no [median wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_wasp) queen, because there's no red.
Maybe a [tree wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichovespula_sylvestris)?

**TL;DR:** Can you help me identify this buzzer?

---

*End of story:*
After a lot of buzzing on her side, me chasing her with glass and cardboard in hand, and she dozing off two times in very uncomfy places (I was a bit embarassed about how un-hospitably dusty everything was), she settled for a box of clothing and snuggled her way into my shirts. I praised her sense of Cozyness, but then carefully emptied the box piece by piece outside and found her inbetween a flowery garment. She slowly stuck her head out from the folds ("DUUUUUUDE, again?!") and flew around the terrace for a while. I hope she's found a snug place out there.

Comment: It really is beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

I presume it is a female *[Dolichovespula adulterina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichovespula_adulterina)* living in the Palearctic (Austria and Germany) and Nearctic regions.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]